# Field not found: 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.Container' when upgrading to bot framewotk 3.8.1

Tags: c#, botframework

We are using Auth bot and after upgrading the bot framework to 3.8.1 we have been getting the following exception when trying to log into our bot:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Field not found: 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.Container'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.MissingFieldException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at AuthBot.Controllers.OAuthCallbackController.<OAuthCallback>d__3.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine) at AuthBot.Controllers.OAuthCallbackController.OAuthCallback(String code, String state, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass12.<GetExecutor>b__8(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

I'm guessing there should be somewhere where we should add Conversation.Container but not sure where.

Here is some relevant code we have:

```
public class CustomModule : Module
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Allows adding custom registrations to the container builder.
        /// In this case we are adding the CustomPostToUser registration.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            Ensure.ArgIsNotNull(builder, nameof(builder));

            builder.RegisterType<CustomPostToUser>().Keyed<IPostToBot>(typeof(CustomPostToUser)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterAdapterChain<IPostToBot>
            (
                typeof(EventLoopDialogTask),
                typeof(SetAmbientThreadCulture),
                typeof(PersistentDialogTask),
                typeof(ExceptionTranslationDialogTask),
                typeof(SerializeByConversation),
                typeof(CustomPostToUser),
                typeof(LogPostToBot)
            )
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers the given adapter chain to the container builder.
        /// </summary>
        public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, SimpleActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle> RegisterAdapterChain<TLimit>(ContainerBuilder builder, params Type[] types)
        {
            Ensure.ArgIsNotNull(builder, nameof(builder));

            return
                builder
                .Register(c =>
                {
                    var service = default(TLimit);
                    return types.Aggregate(service, (current, t) => c.ResolveKeyed<TLimit>(t, TypedParameter.From(current)));
                })
                .As<TLimit>();
        }
    }

    static MessagesController()
    {

        Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterType<MessageActivityLogger>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();
            builder.RegisterModule(new ReflectionSurrogateModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new CustomModule());
        });

    }
```

Comment: Ravit, the way you are registering the items in the container is strange. You are using InokeMember because Update was deprecated right? Consider using Conversation.UpdateContainer and pass lambda as a parameter. Let me know if that helped

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunatelly I still get the same exception when clicking authenticate. Maybe I'm missing some module registration?

Comment: can you post the updated code please? Why are you registering the adapter chain again?

Comment: Sure, updated the code. I'm registering it again to override the default bot framework exception ("sorry my bot code is having an issue" with something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, seems that this happened because the authbot library also needs to be updated for the authentication to work with the new bot framework version.